# Cannot get Spring 2.5 work with Tomcat 5

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

I am writing a web project that uses Spring Framework 2.5 on top of Apache Tomcat 5.0 with JDK 1.4.2.

When Tomcat got started up, it never loaded up Spring.

The Web.xml is like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
<display-name>TestSpring25Web</display-name>
<listener>
    <description>
  loads the spring application context on startup
</description>
    <display-name>spring application context loader listener</display-name>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/web-applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>locatorFactorySelector</param-name>
    <param-value>
  classpath:Spring-config.xml
</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>parentContextKey</param-name>
    <param-value>businessBeanFactory</param-value>
</context-param>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<resource-ref>
    <description>DB Connection</description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/TestDB</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
<servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>QueryDS</display-name>
    <servlet-name>QueryDS</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>servlet.QueryDS</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<!-- DWR -->
<servlet>
    <display-name>DWR Servlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>dwr-invoker</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.directwebremoting.servlet.DwrServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>debug</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>QueryDS</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/QueryDS</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dwr-invoker</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/dwr/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

The "web-applicationContext.xml" is like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.0.xsd">

</beans>
```

The Console gave me the following log stack trace:

SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1680)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4149)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4705)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
25/06/2012 5:16:28 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Skipped installing application listeners due to previous error(s)
25/06/2012 5:16:28 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
25/06/2012 5:16:28 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Context [/TestSpring25Web] startup failed due to previous errors

Can anyone help with some ideas? Thanks!

Cheers,
Alex

Comment: Check out your console and all Tomcat `/logs`. There must be an error somewhere that caused "*previous error(s)*"

Comment: Put the error/exception in your question (you can edit it at any time)

Comment: If this is a new project, stop immediately. Use Spring 3.1 and Tomcat 6. Your versions are being phased out.

Comment: Or Tomcat 7, and JDK7. JDK 1.4.2 is not supported for some time now, and is completely obsolete.

Comment: if it is a new project , then move to tomcat 7 and use latest stable release of spring is better, and error seems some jar is missing from your class path.

Comment: Hi all, I know these are old stuff, but I has to as we are working on adding new things on top of the existing old system which is even JDK 1.4 and Spring 2.5. Thanks very much for all your responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the error you are missing the spring jars in your classpath, the easiest solution would be to copy the spring jar (the one that contains the class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener) to the lib folder under tomcat.

Comment: Are you serious?! Did you look at the question? there is a clear line there: "SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener", and putting jars in the lib is not always a bad idea it really depends on what you need. Can you please explain why you downvoted this? The guy accepted the answer, meaning it worked!!!

Comment: you are right on the CNFE... deleted my comment. I can't upvote again. Sorry :(

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Maven? It's entirely possible that you have version mismatches between different Spring artefacts, where one is calling in an older dependency that the other artefacts you depend on. I've seen this manifest itself in a `ClassNotFoundException` before.

1. Make sure you've got all the dependencies you should have on the classpath (probably `spring-web`)
2. Make sure there are no dependency version conflicts
3. Seriously consider trying to use newer versions of everything if possible!